# What is the regex value for "inet video n##-#######"?

Tags: regex

What is the regex value for the string "inet video n##-#######"? Assuming # is a digit (0-9) and the dash symbol is optional.

Two string examples are:

- inet video n01-0110575
- inet video n010144688

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `\d` for digits.
2. Use `{}` for quantifiers.
3. Use `?` for zero or one occurrence.
4. Use Google to learn the rest of the regex syntax.

   ```
   inet video n\d{2}-?\d{7}
   ```

Comment: @SebastianProske Yes a typo... Thanks for the correction!